# Where to place Moq dlls in the project?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, c#-4.0, mocking

My application has 3 layers(WebProject, UnitTestProject and CoreProject), to use mocking framework for unit testing where to place Moq dlls ?

Comment: you need to place it in your UnitTestProject ...

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I am assuming from the question title you are intending to use Moq, but the theory remains the same for other frameworks</sub>

You can use Nuget to install [moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) into the `UnitTestProject`

[image]

None of the other layers should be aware of mocks or mocking, e.g. your layers would have an IThing and the Mock would satisfy that interface.

**UnitTestProject**

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
   var mock = new Mock<IThing>();
   // set ups

   var sut = new ThingHandler();
   sut.Act(mock.Object);

   // Assert
}
```

**Core Project**

```
public ThingHandler
{
    public result Act(IThing input)
    {
       //do stuff to an IThing
    }
}
```

As you can see the Core Project, doesn't need to know what is satisfying the IThing interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should place all your mock dll's in your `UnitTestProject` itself and no where else. For example, if you are using MS Moles and Pex framework for mocking; once your right click on a dll and choose *create moles* it will automatically create and place the mocked/moled dll in your *Reference* folder.

Moreover, your other project/layer have no business with those mocked dll's and so they should not know about the same.